# How to add local storage to my increase/decrease font script?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, font-size

I'll admit I'm still pretty new to learning Javascript and I am struggling to understand how to add local storage to my increase/decrease font size script I cobbled together. I'd like it to save the user's chosen font size upon refresh or when going to another page but I'm stumped.

I've tried adding local storage in a couples times but the script stops working so I'm sure I'm doing it all wrong. Haven't quite had that "AHA!" moment yet with local storage. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's the base script:

```
 var changeFontSize = function (increaseFont) {
    var fontTargets = new Array('body', 'p', 'table', 'tr', 'td', 'tbody', '.postcolor');

    fontTargets.forEach(function (element) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var newFontSize;
        var currentFontSize = $element.css('font-size');
        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);

        if (increaseFont) {
            $element.css('font-size', 0);
            newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 1.05;
        } else {
            newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 0.9;
        }

        $element.css('font-size', newFontSize);
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Reset Font Size
    var originalFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');

    $(".resetFont").click(function () {
        $('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
    });
    // Increase Font Size
    $(".increaseFont").on('click', function () {
        changeFontSize(true);
    });
    // Decrease Font Size
    $(".decreaseFont").on('click', function () {
        changeFontSize(false);
    });
});
```

I tried adding local storage to my script to save the user's preferences on refresh, but each attempt has caused the script to stop working all together.